# How to handle backyard pet burials at home sale?

Tags: death

We will sell the family house in Louisiana soon, and there are multiple pet (mostly dog) burials in the backyard, 15+ years old, no deeper than two feet (deeper than that, and you'll hit water in this part of La.) What responsibility do we have to remove and/or notify the home purchaser of these burials?

(I didn't find a "real estate" stackexchange to post this, so not really sure where it goes...)

Comment: Welcome! There is a home improvement stack, I assume there it is not better fitting than here, but maybe more knowledge for good answers. 15+ years, does this mean, the "newest burial" is 15 years ago?

Comment: "Legal" might be the most fitting stack for this; either way, it's not really within the scope of this stack.

Comment: Agreed, this is a legal question, not pets or home improvement. Backyard pet burial is officially forbidden in some jurisdictions, common in others. If it wasn't approved if at the time, this is _probably_ a defect you have to disclose even if there wouldn't be much left by now. But I Am Not A Lawyer.

Comment: Hi, as a moderator for this site I can move your question over to Legal.SE if you want. That way you don't need to write the same question again in a different place. Just add a comment below mine if you agree to migrate this question and I'll see it done.

Comment: Thanks @Elmy - please do it.